# Change position of background image on hover

Tags: html, css

I have a png with 2 of the same images except for the text color.

I'm trying to change the position of my background image on hover so that it looks like the text color is changing.

I have this in css

```
.twitter { 
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    width:184px;
    height:83px;
    background:url(../images/twitter.png) 0 0 no-repeat;
    top:276px;
    right:34px;
}
.twitter:hover {
    background:url(../images/twitter.png) 0 -82px no-repeat;
}
```

I have this in my html:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/simplio_sa" class="twitter"></a>
```

The first problem is that the image does not move/change to show the other text color.

The other problem is that when I put the cursor over the image it isn't clickable. The cursor does not change.

Comment: you have 2 different images or you want to change the position of already loaded background-image?

Comment: Can u make Fiddle with your images?

Comment: Its a png with 2 of the same images on but 1 has different text color so when you hover over the image it moves and looks like the text changes color.

Comment: The reason why we want a fiddle is because your code is correct, it should work. So there must be something else wrong, like the image, or maybe you're cached, or ... something, but whatever it is, it'll be easier for us to help you by seeing this issue in action.

Comment: You edited your post, and now your code is not correct, it's switching from `logo.png` to `twitter.png`, is your actual code like that? Or just an editing typo?

Comment: It works on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eMG99/ strange why its not working on my local machine. Thanks for the help. Will try look what is causing this elsewhere

Comment: Because you are using different images both time.

Comment: Try changing your z-index value. - @spuggy

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the image was underneath other elements so I changed the z-index to 99999.

Comment: Using z-index 9999 is really inconsistent, it makes me sad :( A z-index 1 higher is already good you know ^^ If you want to add another overlay you want to use 99999? Why not 1, 2, 3, 4, etc? Just small details.